# XRUN Callback errors running JackD since 19.10 update

Tags: sound, dell, ubuntu-studio, jack

Dell XPS 13, Ubuntu Studio 19.10

```
uname -a
Linux ustudio 5.3.0-42-lowlatency #34-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 28 06:31:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I updated this machine OS from previous version just recently. Ever since I'm plagued with XRUN errors when running JackD and cannot get sound to play properly, even via inbuilt sound card.  There is an absolute lack of anything on how to try and figure out what is causing these problems that I can find, so can someone else help?

Setting configuration and restarting Jackd from Ubuntu Studio Control has no effect, so it's really hard to try anything out. For instance, I stop jackd forceably via kill, set and apply new settings e.g.
[Studio Control settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWHeH.png)

but 
`ps aux | grep /usr/bin/jackd`
gives

```
chippyash   4686  0.0  0.0  96904  9956 ?        Ss   22:52   0:00 /usr/bin/jackdbus auto
chippyash   4701  0.6  0.5 250484 95180 ?        SLsl 22:52   0:01 /usr/bin/jackd -T -ndefault -t 200 -p 2048 -R -T -d alsa -n 2 -r 44100 -p 1024 -d hw:PCH,0 -X raw
```

clearly showing that new settings have not taken effect.  These above were a previous attempt and followed by a reboot for them to take effect.

Are there any tools, commands etc that I can use to try and figure out what are causing the XRUNs?  At the moment the system is unusable.

BTW, I've disconnected my normal audio interfaces to see if they were causing problems, but no. This is still occurring with nothing connected.

TIA.